# SMTP mailing on my website

Tags: php, mysql, email, smtp

I try to set my php mail script to SMTP mail script beacuse my hosting provider does not allow to send mails without verifiny.
I'm trying send emails from my website to my gmail account.
I have to send SMTP mail but i could not transform that script to SMTP mail form.
Here is the code below:

```
   <?php

$websitename="My site name"; 

$allowtypes=array("jpg", "png", "gif");
$myemail="muratcol@gmail.com"; // THIS IS THE MAIL ADDRESS THAT I TRY TO SEND
$priority="2"; 
$allowattach="1"; 
$max_file_size="1500";
$max_file_total="3000";
$submitvalue="Send"; 
$resetvalue="Reset";
$defaultsubject="No subject"; 
$use_subject_drop=false;
$subjects=array("Department 1", "Department 2", "Department 3");
$emails=array("dept_1@domain.com", "dept_2@domain.com", "dept_3@domain.com");
$thanksmessage="Thank you"; 
function get_ext($key) { 
    $key=strtolower(substr(strrchr($key, "."), 1));
    $key=str_replace("jpeg", "jpg", $key);
    return $key;
}

function phattach($file, $name, $boundary) {

    $fp=fopen($file, "r");
    $str=fread($fp, filesize($file));
    $str=chunk_split(base64_encode($str));
    $message="--".$boundary."\n";
    $message.="Content-Type: application/octet-stream; name=\"".$name."\"\n";
    $message.="Content-disposition: attachment; filename=\"".$name."\"\n"; 
    $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64\n";
    $message.="\n";
    $message.="$str\n";
    $message.="\n";

    return $message;
}

function clean_msg($key) {
    $key=str_replace("\r", "", $key);
    $key=str_replace("\n", "", $key);
    $find=array(
        "/bcc\:/i",
        "/Content\-Type\:/i",
        "/Mime\-Type\:/i",
        "/cc\:/i",
        "/to\:/i"
    );
  $key=preg_replace($find, "", $key);
  return $key;
}

$error="";
$sent_mail=false;

If($_POST['submit']==true) {
    extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);

        If(trim($yourname)=="") { 
            $error.="İsminizi giriniz!<br />";
        }

        If(trim($youremail)=="") { 
            $error.="E-Posta adresinizi giriniz!<br />";
        } Elseif(!preg_match("/^\w+([\.-]?\w+)*@\w+([\.-]?\w+)*(\.\w{2,})+$/", $youremail)) {
            $error.="Wrong mail address.<br />";
        }

        If(trim($emailsubject)=="") {
            $emailsubject=$defaultsubject;
        }

        If(trim($yourmessage)=="") { 
            $error.="You didnt enter your message!<br />";
        }

        If($allowattach > 0) {

            If((array_sum($_FILES['attachment']['size'])) > ($max_file_total*1024)) {

                $error.="Max".$max_file_total."kb<br />";

            } Else {

                For($i=0; $i <= $allowattach-1; $i++) {

                    If($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i]) {

                        If(!in_array(get_ext($_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i]), $allowtypes)) {

                            $error.= "Unvalid extension: ".$_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i]."<br />";

                        } Elseif(($_FILES['attachment']['size'][$i]) > ($max_file_size*1024)) {

                            $error.= "Picture so high : ".$_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i].";

                        } 

                    } 

                } 

            } 

        } 

    If($error) {

        $display_message=$error;

    } Else {

        If($use_subject_drop AND is_array($subjects) AND is_array($emails)) {
            $subject_count=count($subjects);
            $email_count=count($emails);

            If($subject_count==$email_count) {

                $myemail=$emails[$emailsubject];
                $emailsubject=$subjects[$emailsubject];

            } // If $subject_count

        } // If $use_subject_drop

        $boundary=md5(uniqid(time()));

        $headers="Return-Path: <".clean_msg($youremail).">\n";
        $headers.="From: ".clean_msg($yourname)." <".clean_msg($youremail).">\n";
        $headers.="X-Mailer: PHP/".phpversion()."\n";
        $headers.="X-Sender: ".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."\n";
        $headers.="X-Priority: ".$priority."\n"; 
        $headers.="MIME-Version: 1.0\n";
        $headers.="Content-Type: multipart/mixed; boundary=\"".$boundary."\"\n";
        $headers.="This is a multi-part message in MIME format.\n";

        $message = "--".$boundary."\n";
        $message.="Content-Type: text/html; charset=\"utf-8\"\n";
        $message.="Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable\n";
        $message.="\n";
        $message.=clean_msg(nl2br(strip_tags($yourmessage)));
        $message.="\n";

        If($allowattach > 0) {

            For($i=0; $i <= $allowattach-1; $i++) {

                If($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i]) {

                    $message.=phattach($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][$i], $_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i], $boundary);

                } 

            } 

        } 
    $message.="--".$boundary."--\n";

    $adjunto_name=$_FILES['attachment']['name']; 
    $adjunto_type=$_FILES['attachment']['type']; 
    $adjunto_size=$_FILES['attachment']['size']; 
    $adjunto_temp=$_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name']; 

    if(is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][0]) && is_uploaded_file($_FILES['attachment']['tmp_name'][1])){


        If(!mail($myemail, clean_msg($emailsubject), $message, $headers)) {

            Exit("Problem !!!\n");

        } Else {

            $sent_mail=true;

        }
}else{

    $error.="Please upload photo.";
    $display_message=$error;
}

} 

} 
?>
```

Comment: You have an unmatched double quote in this line `$error.= "Picture so high : ".$_FILES['attachment']['name'][$i].";`

Comment: Use a library to do this rather than doing it yourself. try [swiftmail](http://swiftmailer.org/), or [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/). There are others.